# cannot read property "getChild" of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a react application. I am trying to call a function from my render function. The function I am calling uses getChild method. I am getting an error saying "cannot read property "getChild" of undefined". It works fine if I dont call it from render method.

This is the function and how I am calling it

```
handlePlay() {
    //this.props.playButtonClickedActio
    console.log("handle play ")
    console.log("hii" + player.getChild('ControlBar').getChild('ProgressControl').currentWidth())
}

render() {
    if (this.props.sentance_selected_reducer.flag) {
        this.handlePlay();
    }
```

player is defined like this in componentDidMount

```
this.video = player = videojs(this.video_el, options).ready(function () {
    self.player = this;
    self.player.on('play', that.handlePlay);
});
```

Comment: What is the value for player? Where have you defined it?

Comment: `player.getChild(...)` returns `undefined`, whereas it should return an object.

Comment: @ishwarrimal please see my updates

Comment: Where is "player" defined?

Comment: Have you tried passing `player` as a parameter into `handlePlay()`, like so, `handlePlay(player)`? I haven't done anything with react yet, so I could be wrong, but this is a scope issue. `player` is defined outside of the scope of `handlePlay()`. You even said that when you said, "It works fine if I dont call it from render method." So change the scope of where `player` gets defined, or pass it into the `handlePlay()` function.

Comment: But player is defined outside the class. That means it's global

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to do things from the `render` function. It's purpose is to render content based on some data.

The reason it returns undefined is that you are within the render method, so basically nothing is rendered yet. The player does not exist until the render function finishes.

Instead, you should handle stuff like this in the `componentDidMount` method, which is called after every `render` finishes.

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.sentance_selected_reducer.flag) {
        this.handlePlay();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will be called only once right? I want to execute the function everytime the row gets clicked and flag gets set to true

Comment: @ApurvG This will be called every time the component re-renders. Basically after every render method. It's the same as writing it in the `render` method.